require() error on node.js hosted with Plesk
I'm using Plesk to host a node.js app. In local theres is no problem, but when I upload the files, node cannot find one of my files.
I have the next in my app.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const { statusRouter } = require('./routes/status');
const { uploadCollectionRouter } = require('./routes/upload_collection');

but the host throws the next error
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './routes/status'
Require stack:
- /var/www/vhosts/go-capr.com/cerambyx_api/routes/upload_collection.js
- /var/www/vhosts/go-capr.com/cerambyx_api/app.js
- /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
    at Module.require (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/go-capr.com/cerambyx_api/routes/upload_collection.js:4:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/www/vhosts/go-capr.com/cerambyx_api/routes/upload_collection.js',
    '/var/www/vhosts/go-capr.com/cerambyx_api/app.js',
    '/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js'
  ]
}

I don't know how to face this problem, because the path seems to be ok. The node version on plesk is 16.20.2
treeview:
app.js
routes/status.js
routes/upload_collection.js
controllers/controller_status.js
controllers/controller_upload_collection.js

status.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { getStatus } = require('../controllers/controller_status');

router.get('/', getStatus);

module.exports = { statusRouter: router };

controller_status.js
const getStatus = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      // Aquí podrías incluir lógica adicional para verificar el estado del servidor si fuera necesario
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Cerambyx API v1 funcionando' });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error); // Pasar el error al siguiente middleware para manejarlo
    }
  };
  
  module.exports = { getStatus };

app.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const { statusRouter } = require('./routes/status');
const { uploadCollectionRouter } = require('./routes/upload_collection');

...

// Rutas
app.use('/status', statusRouter);
app.use('/upload-collection', uploadCollectionRouter);


...


Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It needs to be confirmed there's no problem in other environments. There is supposed to be routes/status.js relatively to app.js, no case difference. There's very little room for error. This part looks suspicious and could be a potential cause, '/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js , custom module loader is the only thing that could affect how it works if file path is ok

@EstusFlask I've just added more info from the source code.

Try require('./routes/status.js') instead to see if there's any difference. Make sure CWD is the project root when app.js runs.  The problem is very specific to your environment, specifically passenger where the error occurs. This looks low-profile and may have better chances to be solved in their repo

I'm a newbie in node.js and more newbie in host environment. This is for a university proyect, so, could you give a web or tutorial to read about? I don't know how to check this, I don't have permissions to use SSH in the hosting, only the panel and ftp. Thank you @EstusFlask

How do you run app.js?

Plesk sais that first request made to the server trigger the launch of node.js. Seems to have all setup done well, but for some reason, the app.js (all project) runs ok on local, but in host seems to be a different way to achived the path. I don't know, sorry. And the support of plesk doesn't help to much.

But how does plesk know that it needs app.js to run? Is it something like this? https://conetix.com.au/support/running-a-node-js-application-with-plesk/#Instructions Here app root was supposed to be the root of your project where app.js is, and startup file is app.js with no path. I'd expect it to be this way already, but this is something that the question omits. Did you try require('./routes/status.js') with the extension as suggested?

Yes, point 3 application startup file. Who wait, I didn't see the extension @EstusFlask I will try it and give feedback.
